# Has quantum mechanics been able to define the centre of a black hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, higgs, singularities

It is said that quantum mechanics has defined everything we observed everything so far, but did it predict the existence of the Higgs Boson beforehand and has it been able to define the Singularity?

Comment: It looks like the terms 'quantum mechanics', 'black hole', 'higgs boson', and 'singularity' just came spilling out without much rationale and understanding of their meanings. Could you add some references to things you've read to explain more fully what exactly they've got to do with each other in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Quantum mechanics (QM) has furnished extremely accurate explanations for an impressive list of things that determine how our world works, but not everything.

The Higgs particle was predicted by QM years ago, and its recent discovery with the predicted characteristics represents yet another triumph of the so-called standard model of particle physics, which has QM as its primary mathematical underpinning.

If by "singularity" you mean the one which is thought to exist at the center of a black hole, this is something predicted not by QM but by general relativity (GR). In this context it is important to note that at present, we do not have a model in hand which merges QM and GR- which merger is considered a prerequisite to fully understand what was going on during the earliest stages of the big bang, when gravitational effects were so powerful that they dominated the quantum-mechanical interactions of the fundamental particles that existed at that time.